# Não consigo digitar em input

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou com um problema numa landing page que estou desenvolvendo. Não sou developer profissional e nunca tive um problema parecido.

Não consigo digitar em nenhum dos inputs que tem na página. Eu vi alguns links onde o problema era uma div em cima dos inputs, mas esse não é o caso. Eu consigo clicar no campo, mas quando vou digitar não aparece texto algum. O engraçado é que se eu tentar colar um texto no input, ele aparece normalmente.

Segue url para visualização: http://docs.wdesign.com.br/realiz-landingpage/

Alguém tem alguma idéia do que pode ser? HTML, CSS, JS? 
Ficarei muito grato com qualquer ajuda!

Comment: Olá @joaorennato seja bem-bindo ao SOpt, 
Sua pergunta não está muito clara quanto ao erro que pretende resolver.
Poderia dar mais informações? Acontece em todos os navegadores, no console de desenvolvedor tem algum erro? Será que os inputs da página não estão disable ou com readonly?
Recomendo também a leitura: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

No ficheiro `site.js` tens este código:

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.first-form', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
        transfere_dados();
    }
});

// e logo de seguida outro igual...
$(document).on('keypress', '.send-form', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
        envia_email();
    }
});
```

Ele está a impedir que os caracteres inseridos sejam usados. Retira isso, ou pelo menos coloca o `e.preventDefault();` dentro do `if (keycode == '13') {`

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Agradeço demais pela ajuda, eu não ia conseguir encontrar esse erro nunca kkk Muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0):

Estive a olhar o site e no teu **js** (`site.js`)
estas a capturar o `keypress` e usar `preventDefault` logo de seguida, tenta meter `preventDefault` dentro do `if (keycode == '13')`

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.first-form', function (e) {
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
        e.preventDefault();
        transfere_dados();
    }

});

$(document).on('submit', '[name="send-form"]', function (e) {
    envia_email();
});

$(document).on('keypress', '.send-form', function (e) {
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
        e.preventDefault();
        envia_email();
    }
});
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Agradeço demais pela ajuda, eu não ia conseguir encontrar esse erro nunca kkk Muito obrigado!!!